# One form writes to db other does not

Tags: php, css, mysql, forms

I got two forms that are similar, both write to the same db, but different tables.
using the same type of fields, varchar.

when i post data on both forms i get a successful message, suppose to only appear once data is written to DB successfully. used the following tutorial to create my first form: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LC9GaXkdxF8&t=4482s". trying to create a register and login system based on it, but data not writing to db.

one form (one from video) is writing data to the DB the other is not. not sure what would be the cause.
Would anyone know what could be the issue?

Form that works and writes to DB:

```
    <form action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username">
        <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="E-mail">
        <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
        <input type="password" name="pwd-repeat" placeholder="Repeat Password">
        <button type="submit" name="signup-submit">Signup</button>
        <?php

    //if an error occurs 
    if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
        if ($_GET['error'] == 'emptyfields') {
            echo '<p>Fill in all the fields!</p>';
        }
        else if ($_GET['error'] == 'invaliduidmail') {
            echo '<p>Invalid username and email</p>';
        }
        else if ($_GET['error'] == 'invaliduid') {
            echo '<p>Invalid username</p>';
        }
        else if ($_GET['error'] == 'invalidmail') {
            echo '<p>Invalid email</p>';
        }
        else if ($_GET['error'] == 'passwordcheck') {
            echo '<p>Passwords do not match</p>';
        }
        else if ($_GET['error'] == 'usertaken') {
            echo '<p>Username is alread used!</p>';
        }
    }
    //if succesfull         
    else if (isset($_GET['signup']) == 'success'){
        echo '<p>signup succesfull!!!</p>';
    }

     ?>
    </form>
```

Form below does not seem to be working. (note i did do some minor change to PHP file includes/signup.inc.php as i added a few more fields)
for some reason the below tag is not appearing on stack overflow

"form action="includes/signup.inc.php" class="form-signin" method="post""
but i did add it, so quoting instead to see if it is visible.

```
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Create Account</h1>
        <label for="inputUserName" class="sr-only">User Name</label>
        <input name="userName" type="text" id="inputUserName" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name" >
        
        <label for="inputFullName" class="sr-only">Full Name</label>
        <input name="FullName" type="text" id="inputFullName" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" >

        <label for="inputAge" class="sr-only">Age</label>
        <input name="Age" type="text" id="inputAge" class="form-control" placeholder="Age" >
        
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input name="Email" type="text" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" >
        
        <label for="inputPhoneNumber" class="sr-only">Phone Number</label>
        <input name="Contact" type="tel" id="inputPhoneNumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" >
        
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input  name="pwd" type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" >

        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Confirm Password</label>
        <input name="ConfirmPwd" type="password" id="inputConfirmPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" >
        
        <button type="submit" name="signup-submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" >Register</button>
        <p class="text-center">Already Registered? <a href="SignIn.php">Sign in here</a> </p>  
    <?php
    //check for errors on the FORM
    //if an error occurs 
    if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
        if ($_GET['error'] == 'emptyfields') {
            echo '<p>Fill in all the fields!</p>';
        }
        else if ($_GET['error'] == 'invaliduidmail') {
            echo '<p>Invalid username and email</p>';
        }
        else if ($_GET['error'] == 'invaliduid') {
            echo '<p>Invalid username</p>';
        }
        else if ($_GET['error'] == 'invalidmail') {
            echo '<p>Invalid email</p>';
        }
        else if ($_GET['error'] == 'passwordcheck') {
            echo '<p>Passwords do not match</p>';
        }
        else if ($_GET['error'] == 'usertaken') {
            echo '<p>Username is alread used!</p>';
        }
    }
    //if succesfull
    else if (isset($_GET['signup']) == 'success'){
        echo '<p>Register was succesfull!!!</p>';
    }

     ?>
    </form>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The code for the second form is incomplete - please edit your question to include all the relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help - we also need to see the code that is processing the form because that could be where the problem is. Please also include the details of any error messages (on the screen, in the logs etc) and details of exactly what is going wrong - it is difficult to help fix a problem when we don't know what it is :)

Answer (score 0):

You have not added `<form action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="post">` on top on second form.

Comment: not sure why it seems to have been cut out, but u have that on my form:

Comment: I have added that in the form, but for some reason it is not displaying on stackover flow.
Would send image of context but not sure how to upload image. and when i edit the below is in the second form:
<form action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="post">

On my side i see that